# Folder in Explorer not available in SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, open-with-explorer

I have a document library in a site which is visible in Explorer view but not available in SharePoint online. How to make it available in SharePoint online? I guess the folder was created using explorer view.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean that you create a folder (document library) through explorer view but it does not show in the SharePoint Online site collection?

Per my knowledge, you cannot create a document library through explorer view. You should create the document library in the SharePoint Online site collection.

Comment: Actually it was not created by me. I’m the admin. I suspect that the end user has created a folder using explorer view and is not appearing in SharePoint online. I’ve instructed the user to copy the contents from the folder to SharePoint document library and then delete the folder in explorer view which should fix the issue I guess right?

Comment: Yes, this is a feasible method.